# Get File object onActivityResult when select Image

Tags: java, android, media-queries, media

I am able to get a `Bitmap` from images in android, but I'm in trouble when I try to get a `File` object. My question is how can I get a `File` object when `onActivityResult` returns.

Here goes my code:

**To open images selection:**

```
private void setUpAddMorePicturesClick() {
    Button btnAddPictures = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add_pictures);
    btnAddPictures.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.text_select_picture)),
                                        ConstantValues.REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}
```

**OnActivityResult Method:**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == ConstantValues.REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE)
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {

                //Uri uri = data.getData();
                //String uriString = uri.toString();
                //File imgFile = new File(uriString);

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();


                File imgFile = new File(picturePath); // <-- NOT WORKING

               // File imgFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(data.getData().getPath());



                //Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                //byte[] s = Utils.bitmapToByteArray(bitmap);

                Snackbar snackbarError = Snackbar.make(rootRelativeLayout, R.string.msg_error_wcf_call_default, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                //new EscortBusiness(this).addImage(s, snackbarError);
                new EscortBusiness(this).addImageMultiPart(imgFile, snackbarError);

            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont try to get a File object. You dont need it. Use the uri directly.

Comment: @greenapps actually i need it, I must upload the selected picture, and retrofit methods use a File object as parameter.

Comment: `// <-- NOT WORKING`. Bad error descriotion. Which path did you get? What happens instead?

Comment: Hi I want to do what you wanted to do as well. I got the image data, but i want to feed it to "File" object to upload to server. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use the inputstream from URI cause its schema may be file:// or content://

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()));
```